# ui-router not showing anything instead of <div ui-view>

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a page form, using `ui-router` module. i've created states in my config file. however when opening `account/trade` it only shows `<div ui-view></div>`. Anything i'm missing?

**config**

```
var app = angular.module("KryptoApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.router", "ngCookies", "ngAnimate"]);
// app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
//     $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
// }]);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/static/templates/index.html",
            controller: "IndexController"
        })
        .when("/register", {
            templateUrl: "/static/templates/register.html",
            controller: "RegisterController"
        })
        .when("/Login", {
            templateUrl: "/static/templates/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        })
        .when("/account/trade", {
            templateUrl: "/static/templates/trade.html",
            controller: "TradeController"
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('trade', {
            url: '/account/trade',
            templateUrl: "/static/templates/trade.html",
            controller: "TradeController"
        })
        .state('trade.coin', {
            url: 'account/trade/coin',
            templateUrl: "/static/templates/trade_coin.html",
            controller: "TradeController"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise('/'); 
});

app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider',function($urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}]);
```

**/static/templates/trade.html**

```
<div ui-view>
```

**/static/templates/trade_coin.html**

test

Answer (score 1):

im not sure ngRouter and uiRouter can coexists without harms. Im might be that ngRoute catch the browser location and then dont render your view. And has you dont have ng-view directive, the ngRouter is not able to display the content.

Could you just try to migrate all your $routeProvider.when(.. stuff to $stateProver.state(.. and then stop injecting ngRoute to your application ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `ui-router` you need to configure your routs as below as per [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)  :

```
var app = angular.module("KryptoApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.router", "ngCookies", "ngAnimate"]);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/index.html",
        controller: "IndexController"
    })
    .state('trade', {
        url: '/account/trade',
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/trade.html",
        controller: "TradeController"
    })
    .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/register.html",
        controller: "RegisterController"
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    })
    .state('trade.coin', {
        url: 'account/trade/coin',
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/trade_coin.html",
        controller: "TradeController"
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); 
});

app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```